# How to make create-react-app use npm instead of yarn?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I kind of rushed into creating a React app based on a tutorial that used yarn. Now I'm going to re-create the app from scratch because I'm not satisfied with the reactstrap library, and I'd like to switch to react-bootstrap.

I've re-installed node. However, when I run create-react-app, it says to use "yarn" instead of "npm" as follows:

```
  yarn start
    Starts the development server.

  yarn build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  yarn test
    Starts the test runner.

  yarn eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd react-test
  yarn start
```

I'd like to use npm because it seems like it's more widely used and there are more examples based on it. Am I stuck with yarn, or can I go ahead and use npm?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can either

1) Remove `yarn.lock`, and running `npm i`,

or

2) Run `create-react-app app --use-npm`

Comment: Will this impact the app I created with yarn?

Comment: Nope. It will be fine as long as you remove `yarn.lock`. This should remove the traces of it and any version conflicts. If you want to play safe, you can remove `node_modules`, before running `npm i`. This in turn will reinstall the dependencies and generate the `package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 11):

1 ⇢ If you have installed `create-react-app` then use:

```
create-react-app --use-npm
```

2 ⇢ If you are using `npx` command then use:

```
npx create-react-app --use-npm
```

3 ⇢ For existing `yarn` app, remove the `yarn.lock` file and run:

```
npm i
```

or

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install create-react-app `npm i -g create-react-app --use-npm`
2. Go to desired path using cd command
3. Add --use-npm `create-react-app  my-app-name --use-npm`
   This command will create a folder with the name that you mentioned inside your current path . This folder consists all necessary configuration files needed for a starter code for react application

Answer (score 1):

**# Run this to create-react-app using npm**

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

**# Or run this to create-react-app using yarn**

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps. But I was having the same problem and did this

npx expo-cli init --npm

and it installed with npm

hope this helps you or someone in the future

Comment: The OP specifically asked for create-react-app, not Expo.

Comment: Yeah, that's for React Native. This for React.

Comment: That command is for React Native using Expo, whereas the question is for React using create-react-app.

Comment: I came here looking for a react native answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For latest versions, the flag is changed to `--npm`
So if you want to use npm then use it like

```
npx react-native init YourProject --npm
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem comes to me. I used
"create-react-app  --use-npm".
It works.