# prevent create react app from using yarn by default

Tags: npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

Ever since I installed yarn globally on my computer when ever I use create-react-app for a new react app it automatically uses yarn when I much rather use npm. I know there is a way to force cra to use npm (npx create-next-app my-app --use-npm), but is there a way to prevent yarn from being the default? If not, why does yarn force itself in as the default?

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61938578/9223987) answer for a similar question helps. It worked for me