# How to create react app using yarn instead of npm?

Tags: reactjs, linux, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg

The offical way to create react app is mentioned in [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

i think `npx create-react-app project` automatically detect **yarn** but in my case it doesn't and create react app using **npm** which i don't want.

Second option for me to use `yarn create react-app` for creating react app but it shows multiple warnings:

```
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning "react-scripts > tailwindcss@3.0.22" has unmet peer dependency "autoprefixer@^10.0.2".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9".
warning "react-scripts > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>= 2.7".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
```

so is there any better way to create react app with **npx** (that uses **yarn**)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `yarn` for `create-react-app` as this npm package is not a local dev dependency. It's used to download a template of a React project and [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) package does all the "magic" stuff.

The reason why [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) suggests using `npx` is that it will delete the package after it's used to create a template. This mean when you want to create another react project, it will always use the latest version of `create-react-app`.

Comment: I mean to say that whenever I write npx create-react-app so it generates react app with package-lock.json but I want it to generate yarn.lock

Comment: @SulemanElahi I guess this should help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61938578/8203841

Comment: I meant to say that we use npm to install packages like
npm install package-name
and when we use yarn we usally do something like
yarn add package-name
so is there any alternative of npx in yarn package manager

right now we have yarn create react-app that is alternative of npx create-react-app

thanks for comments

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, in `create-react-app@version-5.0` and above, the expected behavior is:

- To create a project based on `npm`

  ```
  npm init react-app my-app
  ```

  or

  ```
  npx create-react-app my-app
  ```
- To creates a project based on `yarn`

  ```
  yarn create react-app my-app
  ```

See official [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) or [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11778#issuecomment-996488034)