# I tried installing yarn package using powershell. First I typed npm install -g yarn then I typed yarn install. but I got the following error

Tags: powershell, npm, yarnpkg

I tried opening Powershell with Administrative rights and typed
set-executionpolicy remote signed
then tried this again and I still am getting below error.

```
yarn install
yarn install v1.22.11
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > sockjs > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@material-ui/icons/-/icons-4.9.1.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\Win8\\Documents\\Masters Software Engineering\\upstac-ui\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55740247/2060966

Comment: Set-ExecutionPolicy is only for handling PowerShell scripts...
yarn isn't a PowerShell command.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I made a file and named it

> .yarnrc

and put this inside of it

> network-timeout 500000

Have a look:

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/12432