# I was trying to install react-query. But it is not installed. How to solve it

Tags: react-query

---

### Heading

yarn add v1.22.18
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies
caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
**error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@tanstack%2freact-query: Not found".**
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with
the information provided in "G:\Projects\74\doctors-portal-client\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Comment: You could try to delete your `package-lock.json` file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624786/how-to-solve-package-json-found-to-clear-this-warning-remove-package-lock). This file is automatically generated by npm, so don't worry about breaking anything by removing it.

Comment: @NicholasObert I don't think he cares much about the warning but rather the error of yarn not being able to find the `@tanstack/react-query` library.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the error message, you can try to delete your `package-lock.json` file to get rid of the warning. As stated in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json), `package-lock.json` is automatically generated by npm for any operation that modifies the `node_modules` tree or `package.json`, so don't worry about breaking anything by removing this file, as it will be generated the next time you make some changes to your project.